# COBOL printing sorted file redundancy

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to sort a group of items by their itemname, 
here's the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ITEMREC ASSIGN TO 'GROCERY.DAT'.
    SELECT SORT-ITEMREC ASSIGN TO SYSWORK.
    SELECT OUT-ITEMREC ASSIGN TO 'SORTED_GROCERY.DAT'.
```

here is the codeblock for the FILE SECTION:

```
FD ITEMREC.
01 item.
   02 itemnum             PIC X(10).
   02 itemname            PIC X(20).
   02 itemmanufacturer    PIC X(20).
   02 itemquantity        PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
   02 itemprice           PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

SD SORT-ITEMREC.
01 sort-item.
   02 itemname2           PIC X(20).
   02 filler              PIC X(34).

FD OUT-ITEMREC.
01 out-item.
   02 itemname3            PIC X(20).
   02 filler               PIC X(34).
```

here's the sort statement for the PROCEDURE DIVISION:

```
SORT SORT-ITEMREC
     ON ASCENDING KEY itemname
     USING ITEMREC
     GIVING OUT-ITEMREC.
```

Here's the printing of "SORTED_GROCERY.DAT":

```
DISPLAY "".
PERFORM Table-header.
OPEN INPUT OUT-ITEMREC.
PERFORM UNTIL EOF=1
    READ OUT-ITEMREC
         AT END MOVE 1 TO EOF
         NOT AT END PERFORM PRINT-DATA
END-PERFORM.
CLOSE OUT-ITEMREC.
PERFORM Table-footer.
STOP RUN.
```

---

The contents of "SORTED_GROCERY.DAT" are of the sorted value, but when printed, it only prints the first entry of the DAT file only and replaces all other values. But when I print the "GROCERY.DAT" by replacing the "OUT-ITEMREC" into "ITEMREC" in the codeblock above, it prints alright.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

---

Update:

```
Table-header.
   DISPLAY "Items bought by " WITH NO ADVANCING.

   IF csex = "M" THEN
      DISPLAY "Mr. " WITH NO ADVANCING
   END-IF

   IF csex = "F" AND cstatus = "S" THEN
       DISPLAY "Ms. " WITH NO ADVANCING
   END-IF

   IF csex = "F" AND cstatus = "M" THEN
       DISPLAY "Mrs. " WITH NO ADVANCING
   END-IF

   DISPLAY cname WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY ":".

   DISPLAY "".

   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "".
   DISPLAY "[Number of Pieces]    " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "[Item Name]    " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "[Manufacturer]   " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "[Number of Pieces*Price]" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "".
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "====================" WITH NO ADVANCING.


PRINT-DATA.
   DISPLAY itemquantity WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "   " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY itemname WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "   " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY itemmanufacturer WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "   " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY itemquantity WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "*" WITH NO ADVANCING
   DISPLAY itemprice WITH NO ADVANCING.
   DISPLAY "".

   MULTIPLY itemprice BY itemquantity GIVING temp. 
   ADD temp total GIVING total.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the last minute, I mangled the names, so have fixed that, and incorporsated Gilbert's point about the position of the data on the file being sorted.

I think COBOL internal sorts tend to "complicate" things, but that is another issue.

```
SORT SORT-ITEMREC
 ON ASCENDING KEY itemname
 USING ITEMREC
 GIVING OUT-ITEMREC.
```

itemname above is supposed to be defined under the SD for SORT-ITEMREC, you have it instead under the FD for ITEMREC, at least in what you have shown.

If you haven't just typo'd it here, I don't know why that'd not be a compiler error.

What COBOL and Operating System are you using?

Your data-names are too similar, thus easily confused. If you make your data-names more meaningful, you can't even bring the problem about:

```
FD ITEMREC.
01 item.
   02 input-itemnum             PIC X(10).
   02 input-itemname            PIC X(20).
   02 input-itemmanufacturer    PIC X(20).
   02 input-itemquantity        PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
   02 input-itemprice           PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

SD SORT-ITEMREC.
01 sort-item.
   02 filler              PIC X(10).
   02 sortwork-area-only-itemname           PIC X(20).
   02 filler              PIC X(24).

FD OUT-ITEMREC.
01 out-item.
   02 sorted-itemname           PIC X(20).
   02 filler               PIC X(34).

SORT SORT-ITEMREC    
   ON ASCENDING KEY input-itemname
 USING ITEMREC
 GIVING OUT-ITEMREC.
```

When you code something like that (an example, make it as descriptive as possible) you *have* to think to yourself "how can I be sorting on a 'input-itemname', surely I need 'sortwork-area-only-itemname'?

```
SORT SORT-ITEMREC    
   ON ASCENDING KEY sortwork-area-only-itemname
 USING ITEMREC
 GIVING OUT-ITEMREC.
```

The named "sort key" as to be part of the file that is "being sorted", the file which is the SD.

The change in the data-names then reveals your real problem, later on.

You are using your *unsorted* data record-layout. But the file you are reading is the *sorted* one, and you've already discovered that for yourself, you just don't realise yet that it solves your problem.

Give everything good names. Make it obvious. The particular problems should become much clearer to you, and you then get to resolve them yourself.

Please take the time to tell us which compiler, as it seems there is a bug in it, unless the first thing was just a typo - also more difficult to make/easier to spot with good naming.

Answer (score 1):

Your sort item record has to match your item record and your output item record.

Try this.

```
FD ITEMREC.
01 item.
   02 itemnum             PIC X(10).
   02 itemname            PIC X(20).
   02 itemmanufacturer    PIC X(20).
   02 itemquantity        PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
   02 itemprice           PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

SD SORT-ITEMREC.
01 sort-item.
   02 filler              PIC X(10).
   02 itemname2           PIC X(20).
   02 filler              PIC X(24).

FD OUT-ITEMREC.
01 out-item.
   02 filler              PIC X(10).
   02 itemname3           PIC X(20).
   02 filler              PIC X(24).
```

Comment: Try sorting on ascending key itemname2.  It's been a while since I've done COBOL.

Comment: the sorting output is correct, I checked the SORTED_GROCERY.DAT file after execution, everything is in order. The problem lies when accessing that file and printing it. It just prints the first entry and replaces all of the succeeding ones with that entry...

Comment: I'd have to see your table header and print data paragraphs to try and answer your question.  One thing you can try is creating a working storage description of the item record with all the fields, and moving the output item record to that working storage item record.  Your print data paragraph would use the working storage description, which would work for both the input and output item files.

Comment: I added the Print Data and Table Header paragraphs to my post. thanks!

Comment: A good point Gilbert, always a good place to start checking is lengths, positions and types. Helpful.